# How to open an app with the iOS11 integrated qrcode reader

Tags: ios, qr-code, ios11

I want to use the new in-build qrcode reader in the iOS camera to open an app.

I cannot find the right documentation in the API.

Thanks for your help

Best Regards 
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v just tested with various URLs. It seems if the URL is `http` the Camera app opens Mobile Safari. If you know the target app URL (which is declared in the `Info.plist`) you can open the app with QR codes.

(ex) `youtube://user/Apple` --> Opens Youtube app

Comment: that sounds promising, I will try and let you know. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @TibinThomas can you explain what you mean with "universal links"?